# Disable API discovery for API Explorer

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm new to App Engine and am trying to figure out how to disable the API Explorer from showing all my APIs, which are currently public and available to anyone visiting `[MYPROJECT].appspot.com/_ah/api/explorer`

Supposedly Snapchat uses AppEngine, however visiting https://apis-explorer.appspot.com/apis-explorer/?base=https://feelinsonice.appspot.com/_ah/api#p/ does not reveal their APIs.

Viewing network activity for that page you'll see that requests are being made to https://feelinsonice.appspot.com/_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis but returning a `404`.

How do I do the same?

When visiting the API Explorer using my project ID I see this:
[image: APIs Discovery Service]

Is this the culprit?

Comment: I don't understand... you don't want OTHER people to see your APIs?  Because what's the problem with you seeing your own APIs?

Comment: Not right now. Also what would be the solution if you were building something only a private group of people would need and hence no need to build in authorisation. There must be a way to disable discovery?

Others yes. Right now it's public for all to see.

Comment: Pretty sure it isn't actually.  If I go in my API page I don't see whatever APIs you created.  The page would be unmanageable and just... well downright crazy.  Your problem is with people doing what? seeing it in their page? or accessing it through URLs?

Comment: If you visit PROJECTID.appspot.com/_ah/api/explorer it'll show all APIs and let you interact with them. 

E.g. I'm not posting mine, but I just randomly Googled site:appspot.com and found restapi1.appspot.com. Visiting restapi1.appspot.com/_ah/api/explorer reveals his APIs. E.g. https://apis-explorer.appspot.com/apis-explorer/?base=https://restapi1.appspot.com/_ah/api#p/myapi/v1/myapi.data.delete

Comment: Here's another. Proof they're public. Click on them: https://apis-explorer.appspot.com/apis-explorer/?base=https://picturesque-app.appspot.com/_ah/api#p/

Comment: OOOH in that sense, yes.  I thought you were concerned anyone could, from their OWN API explorer, see your project<s API.... yeah it you hit the right url, they will definitely be visible... I figure there should be a way to block this.... how though might be harder to find

Comment: I've searched for a couple of days however I could be wording it wrong. The fact that Snapchat has disabled it hopefully means there is a way.

Comment: I have no clue if that could work or not.... but maybe changing your app.yaml (or appconfiguration.xml if you're not in python) to force a login on that specific url?  I know you can configure Appstat to be "login = admin".... might be able to use a similar method?

Answer (score 2):

Endpoints is the 'culprit'.  I'm assuming you are using endpoints since you've included that tag, and I guess snapchat doesn't use endpoints.

There is nothing you can do to change this other then stop using endpoints.

Comment: Is there an alternative way of having an Android app communicate with an App Engine server then?

Comment: Definately.  Endpoints is a fairly new service that makes certain tasks (eg. authentication) easier.  If you are using Java then just create a plain servet and have your Android app call it.  Serialize your java objects (eg. using gson) to json strings before sending them.

Comment: If I understand well, the Endpoint infra define a *public* API. If you need protect access, OAuth is the right way.